To use CDI or CAI and what transformations to use for API in IICS
To read a REST API or SOAP API in IICS which has a URL and if i wanted to extract fields from the JSON or XML file what transformations should i use.
Can this be done in Cloud Data integration (CDI) or should i use Cloud application integration(CAI)
Which transform will support using the headers and the body as i can see in postman.
I am reading from a REST API and would like to extract the JSON fields, an example would be to get the access_token from a REST API URL and make a GET call.
Anoather would be to make a SOAP API get call and extract the XML fields.
How do i do the above.
The legacy ETL shows the code for the message body as below :
String role_soap = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"+
"<s:Header>"+
"<readoauth>"+context.get_token+"</readoauth>"+
"</s:Header>"+
"<s:Body xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" 
xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">"+
"<RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns=\"http://example.com/wsdl/partnerAPI\">"+

Do i need to include a java transform for the body.
Sorry i am new to the API world and need to do the conversion from legacy ETL to IICS
